# How do I determine a MS Word style's styleId in a macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word

A saved word document saves its style definitions in a single location (styles.xml) and references those styles in the document (document.xml) by the styleId. The styleId can be different than the style name. The style name is what is shown via the user interface.

In my macro I have the line `Set myStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles("myStyle")` and I can browse the properties of `myStyle` via the watch window, but I cannot locate styleId. Is this possible using a macro?